# What is the place to ask questions about Area 51?

Tags: support, area-51

As reported in this site, this is the place where to ask questions about Stack Overflow, Super User, and Server Fault.
Is there a place to ask questions about Area 51?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [the announcement](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/area-51-we-come-in-peace/), this is the place. Just tag your questions [area51](/questions/tagged/area51).

Answer (score 2):

mmyers is correct; I updated the /faq to better reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

This has changed; ask on [Discuss](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/).  From the A51 FAQ:

> ### I still have more questions!
>
> If they're about Area 51, please ask in the Area 51 Discussion Zone. If they're about Stack Exchange in general, though, they're welcome at meta.stackoverflow.com, the Stack Exchange site about Stack Exchange. Either way, somebody may have already asked your question.