# Where should I report bugs I see just on Area 51?

Tags: support, area-51

#### Background

I once asked [What is the place to ask questions about Area 51?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56343/what-is-the-place-to-ask-questions-about-area-51) where Jeff Atwood reported that *Meta Stack Overflow* was the place for such questions. Clearly the question was asked before discussion.area51.stackexchange.com was created.
In [What is the division of labor between MSO and the area51-meta tag on Area 51?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110477/what-is-the-division-of-labor-between-mso-and-the-area51-meta-tag-on-area-51) Robert Cartaino says *Meta Stack Overflow* is not the place for asking about *Area 51*.
In [a recent comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121952/double-encoding-on-area-51#comment324941_121952) a developer said:

> Area 51 bugs actually *do* belong here on Meta (yes, we realize this is a bit confusing). [Area 51 Discussion](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/) is for talking about the proposals themselves, and not so much for pointing out bugs in the software.

Where should I report bugs I see only on *Area 51*?

I can imagine those bugs should be kept in a single place to avoid that who needs to check for those reports should check in two different places, but [the FAQ for *Meta Stack Overflow*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) doesn't report any reference to *Area 51*.
The other problem I see is for those "bugs" for which there is really a setting in the user interface available to Stack Exchange staff; I don't see in which way a question would be interesting for any other users on *Meta Stack Overflow* who don't visit *Area 51* at all. If that is the sign that general code is being used in a way that was not initially planned, or general code is not considering a specific case in which is called, that would probably be a reason to report the bug in the general meta.

Comment: I was going to ask this same question. I've noticed a few recently so this will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bugs were previously off-topic for Discuss and were to be asked here on MSO.  That is no longer the case, as you can see from [their bug tag](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug).  In general only issues affecting more than one site should be brought up here, whereas it's fine for network-wide bugs to be brought up on site Metas if you only notice it there or don't participate on MSO.\

From the A51 FAQ:

> ### I still have more questions!
>
> If they're about Area 51, please ask in the Area 51 Discussion Zone. If they're about Stack Exchange in general, though, they're welcome at meta.stackoverflow.com, the Stack Exchange site about Stack Exchange. Either way, somebody may have already asked your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Area 51's ["meta" site](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Most of the questions are about the individual proposals, but I can't see a problem with reporting a bug there.

Comment: Make sure you tag the question with the [area51-meta] tag. :) I think they also have a [bug] tag there.